# issues with windows 7 installing anything

Tags: windows-7

I have been having issues with installations of any software on windows 7. I do not know when the problem began, but I first noticed it last week when I tried to install Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015. The installation ran to 99% and then just kept running in perpetuity without completing. I ended up having to end the task in order to regain use of my pc. This week I attempted to install TurboTax and ran into the same issue, install to 99% and then it just stalls. Any attempt to run an installation after ending this task fails to even initialize. When I attempt to install Msft Vis Studio I get an error that another installation is in progress. But it isn't.

From what I have gathered there seems to be some issue with my msiserver service. It will start running and then just doesnt stop. I cannot stop it regardless of what admin or ownership roles I assign. I am not a computer expert so I am at a loss at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am on windows 7 enterprise.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.utilityspotlight.aspx. have you tried this?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin The Windows Installer CleanUp utility was pulled from the Microsoft site many years ago, it is no longer available, they pulled it because it screwed up more systems than it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but looks like both programs are using **Windows Installer** to set up, and this is indeed a Windows component.

Since you're using a Enterprise edition of Windows, I'm assuming you are behind a corporate/institution domain and are using a work account (instead of a local Administrator or personal Microsoft account) to log into Windows:

1. Provided you didn't run into problem installing other software, first thing you want to do is to try more Windows Installer packed programs. Popular software like **Google Chrome** and **7-Zip** all provide a special *MSI* installation file. Try to install this file and see if any hangs at ~90%. If the same occurs, you're out of luck. Either contact your domain administrator or seek help from Internet to get rid of these domain policies.
2. Fix your Windows install. It is unlikely to have damaged Windows Installer components and still run Windows fine as usual. Almost all Windows Updates and Microsoft software uses Windows Installer. You should see errors popping up very often, anyway. Use commands like `sfc /scannow` or `dism` to repair your Windows. You may need direct connection to the Internet or a Windows installation media (DVD/USB Drive).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this fix.

1.Click **Start**, and then type Notepad in the Searchbox.

2.Under the Programs heading, click **Notepad.exe**.Copy the following **text**, and then paste it into a notepad:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\msiserver] "DisplayName"="@%SystemRoot%\\system32\\msimsg.dll,-27" "ImagePath"=hex(2):25,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,72,00,6f,00,6f,00,\ 74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,6d,\ 00,73,00,69,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,63,00,20,00,2f,00,56,00,00,00 "Description"="@%SystemRoot%\\system32\\msimsg.dll,-32" "ObjectName"="LocalSystem" "ErrorControl"=dword:00000001 "Start"=dword:00000003 "Type"=dword:00000010 "DependOnService"=hex(7):72,00,70,00,63,00,73,00,73,00,00,00,00,00 "ServiceSidType"=dword:00000001 "RequiredPrivileges"=hex(7):53,00,65,00,54,00,63,00,62,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,\ 00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,43,00,72,00,65,00,61,00,\ 74,00,65,00,50,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,66,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,50,00,72,00,69,\ 00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,4c,00,6f,00,63,00,\ 6b,00,4d,00,65,00,6d,00,6f,00,72,00,79,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,\ 00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,49,00,6e,00,63,00,72,00,65,00,61,00,\ 73,00,65,00,42,00,61,00,73,00,65,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,6f,00,72,00,69,00,74,\ 00,79,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,\ 65,00,43,00,72,00,65,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,50,00,65,00,72,00,6d,00,61,00,6e,\ 00,65,00,6e,00,74,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,\ 00,00,53,00,65,00,41,00,75,00,64,00,69,00,74,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,\ 00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,53,00,65,00,63,00,75,00,72,00,\ 69,00,74,00,79,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,\ 00,53,00,65,00,43,00,68,00,61,00,6e,00,67,00,65,00,4e,00,6f,00,74,00,69,00,\ 66,00,79,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,\ 00,65,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,66,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,53,00,69,00,6e,00,67,00,\ 6c,00,65,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,63,00,65,00,73,00,73,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,\ 00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,49,00,6d,00,70,00,65,00,\ 72,00,73,00,6f,00,6e,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,\ 00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,43,00,72,00,65,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,\ 47,00,6c,00,6f,00,62,00,61,00,6c,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,\ 00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,41,00,73,00,73,00,69,00,67,00,6e,00,50,00,\ 72,00,69,00,6d,00,61,00,72,00,79,00,54,00,6f,00,6b,00,65,00,6e,00,50,00,72,\ 00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,52,00,65,00,\ 73,00,74,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,\ 00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,49,00,6e,00,63,00,72,00,65,00,61,00,73,00,65,00,\ 51,00,75,00,6f,00,74,00,61,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,\ 00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,53,00,68,00,75,00,74,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,6e,00,\ 50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,54,\ 00,61,00,6b,00,65,00,4f,00,77,00,6e,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,68,00,69,00,70,00,\ 50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,4c,\ 00,6f,00,61,00,64,00,44,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,65,00,72,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,\ 76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,00,00 "FailureActions"=hex:84,03,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,14,00,00,\ 00,01,00,00,00,c0,d4,01,00,01,00,00,00,e0,93,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\msiserver\Enum] "0"="Root\\LEGACY_MSISERVER\\0000" "Count"=dword:00000001 "NextInstance"=dword:00000001
```

3.Click File, click **Save As**, and then name the file **Msirepair.reg**.

4.In the Save as type box, click **All Files (*.*)**.

5.In the Save in box, click **Desktop**, and then **clickSave**.

6.On the File menu, click **Exit** to close notepad.

7.On the Desktop, **right-click** Msirepair.reg, and then click Run as **administrator**.

8.If you are prompted to enter an administrator password or provide confirmation, type the **password**, or click Continue.

9.Click Yes when you are prompted to **install** the registry keys.

10.**Restart** the installation process for the program that you want to install.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly this would do?

Comment: Repairs the msiserver service